# Angular $resource and OData strings such as $skip

Tags: angularjs, odata

I am using a $resource in Angular like this:

```
function classResource($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/classes/:classId");
}
```

I now want to add OData query options such as $filter or $skip for server-side filtering and paging.

Do I build them using the same technique as with query string parameters? Or is there another way?

Comment: I think you'd have to build the parameters if you want to use `$resource`. Another option is to use a library like BreezeJS that has built in support for OData.

Answer (score 7):

OK... here is the code I used to build the parameters.

```
    classResource.query({ $skip: 10, $filter: 'value' },
        function (data) {
            vm.classes = data;
        });
```

This seems to produce the desired result: "/api/classes?$filter=value&$skip=10"